# Colour Difference in The Foundry NUKE

Tags: python, rgba, nuke

So I am trying to make a painterly node group with Python code straight so I can use it for future projects but I can't seem to get the power part of the formula in nuke to work from this colour difference formula( I'm also new to Nuke so if there is a better way of writing this please let me know it would be awesome thank you, or if I'm doing this wrong completely also let me know)

> The following formula for color difference is used to create the
> difference image: |(r1,g1,b1) – (r2,g2,b2)| = ((r1 – r2)^2 + (g1
> –g2)^2 + (b1 – b2)^2)^1/2.

```
nRedShuffle = nuke.nodes.Shuffle()
nRedShuffle['red'].setValue('red')
nRedShuffle['green'].setValue('red')
nRedShuffle['blue'].setValue('red')
nRedShuffle['alpha'].setValue('red')

nGreenShuffle = nuke.nodes.Shuffle()
nGreenShuffle['red'].setValue('green')
nGreenShuffle['green'].setValue('green')
nGreenShuffle['blue'].setValue('green')
nGreenShuffle['alpha'].setValue('green')

#...(so on for the rest of rgba1 and rgba2)

nGreenShuffle2 = nuke.nodes.Shuffle()
nGreenShuffle2['red'].setValue('green')
nGreenShuffle2['green'].setValue('green')
nGreenShuffle2['blue'].setValue('green')
nGreenShuffle2['alpha'].setValue('green')

nBlueShuffle2 = nuke.nodes.Shuffle()
nBlueShuffle2['red'].setValue('blue')
nBlueShuffle2['green'].setValue('blue')
nBlueShuffle2['blue'].setValue('blue')
nBlueShuffle2['alpha'].setValue('blue')

#I am having troubles with the powers below

redDiff = nuke.nodes.Merge2(operation='minus', inputs=[nRedShuffle2, nRedShuffle])
redDiffMuli = nuke.nodes.Merge2(operation='multiply', inputs=[redDiff, redDiff])

greenDiff = nuke.nodes.Merge2(operation='minus', inputs=[nGreenShuffle2, nGreenShuffle])
greenDiffMuli = nuke.nodes.Merge2(operation='multiply', inputs=[greenDiff, greenDiff])

blueDiff = nuke.nodes.Merge2(operation='minus', inputs=[nBlueShuffle2, nBlueShuffle])
blueDiffMuli = nuke.nodes.Merge2(operation='multiply', inputs=[blueDiff, blueDiff])

redGreenAdd = nuke.nodes.Merge2(operation='plus', inputs=[redDiffMuli, greenDiffMuli]) 
redGreenBlueAdd =  nuke.nodes.Merge2(operation='plus', inputs=[redGreenAdd, blueDiffMuli])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are at least two ways to implement `Color Difference` formula for two images. You can use `difference` op in Merge node or you can write a formula in field for each channel inside `MergeExpression` node:

[image]

Expression for each channel is as simple as this:

```
abs(Ar-Br)
abs(Ag-Bg)
abs(Ab-Bb)
```

[image]

## Python commands

You can use `.nodes.MergeExpression` methodology:

```
import nuke

merge = nuke.nodes.MergeExpression(expr0='abs(Ar-Br)', 
                                   expr1='abs(Ag-Bg)', 
                                   expr2='abs(Ab-Bb)')
```

or regular `.createNode` syntax:

```
merge = nuke.createNode('MergeExpression')

merge['expr0'].setValue('abs(Ar-Br)')
merge['expr1'].setValue('abs(Ag-Bg)')
merge['expr2'].setValue('abs(Ab-Bb)')
```

## Full code version

```
import nuke
import nukescripts

red = nuke.createNode("Constant")
red['color'].setValue([1,0,0,1])

merge = nuke.createNode('MergeExpression')
merge['expr0'].setValue('abs(Ar-Br)')
merge['expr1'].setValue('abs(Ag-Bg)')
merge['expr2'].setValue('abs(Ab-Bb)')

yellow = nuke.createNode("Constant")
yellow['color'].setValue([1,1,0,1])

merge.connectInput(0, yellow)
nuke.toNode('MergeExpression1').setSelected(True)

nukescripts.connect_selected_to_viewer(0)

# Auto-alignment in Node Graph
for everyNode in nuke.allNodes():
    everyNode.autoplace()
```

**Consider! `MergeExpression` node is much slower that regular `Merge(difference)` node**.